# How do I check the inbound header "content-type" response in mule?

Tags: java, rest, content-type, mule

I've got a flow that processes the response from a REST service:

```
    <http:outbound-endpoint method="GET"
                            address="http://www.SomeAddress.com"
                            exchange-pattern="request-response">
        ...
        <response>
            <json:json-to-object-transformer/>
            <custom-transformer ... />
        </response>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
```

Recently the service has been updated to return html content.  I'd like to be able to identify the content-type in the response:

```
    <http:outbound-endpoint method="GET"
                            address="http://www.SomeAddress.com"
                            exchange-pattern="request-response">
        ...
        <response>
            <choice>
                <when content-type is html>
                    <custom-transformer-for-html ... />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <json:json-to-object-transformer/>
                    <custom-transformer ... />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </response>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
```

Even better, it would be nice to simply throw an exception if the content-type is unrecognized, similar to a traditional switch statement:

```
switch (content-type) {
    case (html) : ...
    case (json): ...
    default: throw exception
}
```

Can a choice statement check the inbound header content-type?  Is the switch with default check possible?  Are there any examples I can look at?

--- Update ---

I tried Davids suggestion below:

```
        <response>                
            <choice>
                <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['Content-Type'].contains('text/html')]">
                    <logger message="when number one invoked" level="WARN"/>
                </when>
                <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['Content-Type'].contains('application/json')]">
                   <logger message="when number two invoked" level="WARN"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <logger message="otherwise invoked" level="WARN"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </response>
```

But now I'm getting the following error when I compile:

```
    cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'choice'. 
    One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer,
    "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter,
    "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-filter, 
    "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-intercepting-message-processor, 
    "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-observer-message-processor,
    "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor, 
    "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor}' is expected. 
    (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)
      org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper:-1 (null)
```

Comment: What Mule version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use a MEL expression in each `<when>` element to test the `Content-Type` header: `#[message.inboundProperties['Content-Type'] == 'text/html']`
- Use the `<otherwise>` element to act as the `default` statement of a `switch`: throw your exception from there.

Comment: I tried adding multiple when statements like in the example on this page, but I end up with an error.  I used "==" and "contains" but the error persists.  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL

Comment: You're missing closing `]` at the end of your expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure why these did not show up in the code above.  They are in  my project.  I'll update the code above.  Even with the missing brackets added I have the same error.

Comment: For a reason that escapes me, Mule's XSD prevents a `choice` in a `response` in an `endpoint`. Does your flow logic allow you to move the `response` outside the `http:endpoint`, say right after it?

Comment: Actually if you put the `choice` after the `http:outbound-endpoint` element, you do not need to put it in a `response` block.

Comment: It looks like if I do that I lose the response information.  I get a NullPointerException when exercising that flow.

Comment: I have a test flow with the above choice copy/pasted right after an `http:outbound-endpoint` element and it works fine, I see "when number one invoked" in the logs.

Comment: Can you send me the xml?  I'd like to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: when using == to compare values keep in mind that Content-Type may contain encoding as well (f.e. `text/html; charset=utf-8`)